# Connect to pc localhost via android phone without using emulator

Tags: java, php, android

i am using async task to login users though a php login page here is my java android code :

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <= 0; ++i) {
        result = this.invokePost(urls[i], this.postData);
    }

    return result;
}

private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    String response = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection e = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      /*  e.setReadTimeout(15000);
        e.setConnectTimeout(15000);*/
        e.setRequestMethod("POST");
        e.setDoInput(true);
        e.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = e.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(this.getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = e.getResponseCode();
        String line;
        if(responseCode == 200) {
            for(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(e.getInputStream())); (line = br.readLine()) != null; response = response + line) {
                ;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
            Log.d("responce code", responseCode + "");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        response ="An exception has occured" + ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("exception",ex.toString());
    }

    return response;
}
```

Login.java :

```
 HashMap PostData = new HashMap();
        PostData.put("username", username);
        PostData.put("password", username);
        BackgroundWorker LoginWorker= new BackgroundWorker(this,PostData);
        LoginWorker.execute("http://192.168.43.22:8080/login.php");
```

I am not using an emulator though i am running the application through my nexus 5 phone , my phone and my pc are both connected to a router wifi

but i am getting a connection exception ( i couldn't ping my pc through my nexus 5 )

how can i open a connection between my phone and my pc

Comment: Uses the PC some kind of firewall? Can you access the web server from another computer/notebook/tablet? Uses the android the WiFi connection in the same network or the cellular connection which may be outside your network.

Comment: are you sure your PC IP address is `192.168.43.22`?

Comment: yes i am sure and  i disable the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Get your pc ip using `ipconfig` in cmd and use it without port

```
LoginWorker.execute("http://192.168.**.**/login.php");
```

if don't work open port 80 in your firewall

Comment: i did that but it seem i can not open a network between my pc and my phone ! i have no idea what is the problem

Comment: You must add new rule for port 80 in Firewall setting